# How should the planetary tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

The word planetary is defined as:

> Adjective
>
> 1. Of, relating to, or belonging to a planet or planets.
> 2. Of or relating to the earth as a planet.

So it makes sense that [planetary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary) has questions about the structure, size, or other qualities of planets.  However, [*Planetary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_%28comics%29) is also a popular comic book series, and is what the first few usages of [planetary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary) are discussing.

What do we do here?  Should we do what we did with [alien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien) and [alien-1979](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-1979)?  Or is the tagging of these questions about *planets* incorrect, and those should have the tag removed and replaced with something else, maybe [planets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets)?

Comment: Since everyone seems to agree the questions that aren't about the comic *Planetary* shouldn't have this tag on them, I've retagged them.  Some didn't have any reason to be tagged with [tag:planets], so I just removed the tag from those.

Answer (score 9):

I think that planetary is okay for the comic series, and questions relating to planets can just use the planet tag.

Comment: This.  Tags are subjects, and thus nouns; `planetary` has to be the name of something for it to be a tag, since it is otherwise an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

I think many new users would find [planetary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary) ambiguous.  [planetary-comic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-comic) for the comic title, and [planets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) for anything dealing with actual planets, would be clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: In principle  this is a good plan, but adding comic to the end of all our comic tags would end up being impractical.

Comment: @Pureferret I don't see the need to add "comic" to the end of *all* our comic tags; only the ones that are potentially confusing (which is a very small subset).

Comment: no I understand that. But I feel it'd be good to be consistent with our tags.

Comment: *Planet Comics* is the title of a really famous, popular, important sci-fi comic book, connected with the famous classic pulpzine *Planet Stories* which published a lot of Bradbury's early work. Never heard of "Planetary".